# Native looking desktop/mobile apps with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, angularjs

From what I've read, AngularJS is perfect for single page applications.

But what additional libraries / components would I need to be able to create an app that looks and feels like a native desktop and/or mobile app?

I'm new to web development and from a beginner's perspective Angular UI seems to have quite a limited number of widget types?

1. Am I missing something obvious and Angular UI / bootstrap is genuinely all you need?
2. Is it possible (common) to integrate other UI libraries with Angular?
3. If 2. is yes, which libraries do you recommend and what's involved? If it's easy to integrate other UI libraries why is there a special "Angular" version of bootstrap - how does this differ from normal bootstrap?
4. Is it common to extend Angular UI and create your own components? Is this recommended?

Comment: I created a desktop level app with AngularJS (hopefully :)). Please check it out https://github.com/zsong/stock-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Angular is quite new, so there aren't so many libraries out there yet. Because if of the nature of angular.js "views" it isn't always required to have an explicit library for UI. (I use bootstrap, but without any angular modules.)
2. Yes. Write some directives and you are good to go.
3. There 2 libraries for bootstrap. One uses the original jQuery bootstrap code, the other doesn't. Why? It is cooler to just `<nav><tab /><tab/></nav>` then writing `div`s and `ul`s. (That maybe because many Flex developer coming to angular)
4. Yes it is common to extend (better: create) your own components. It's recommended because you code becomes much more reusable. Also: You don't like one thing on your component? Simply change the implementation in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is "angular is great, I love not having to muck around with callbacks and the dom to refresh my UI, but I miss jquery mobile's look and feel - is there a way to get both angular's good bits (routing/controllers/directives) and the slick look of jqm'?

Unfortunately, right now the answer is 'errmm, kinda'.  There's a (multiply-forked) library called jqm-angular-adapter at https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter tho the documentation is in German).  Another StackOverflow question may point to a solution - [Using jQuery Mobile Adapter in AngularJS - Applying jqmCompatMode false to Enable Angular Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444764/using-jquery-mobile-adapter-in-angularjs-applying-jqmcompatmode-false-to-enabl) - which I only just found today and will be trying out myself to see if it's the holy grail of routing and moblifying HTML5 screens.